# Viewsonic Monitor Resolution - Drivers are not working

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, resolution

I have Viewsonic va1716w monitor which has VGA/D-SUB video input. I bought new Motherboard Intel DH67GD which has HDMI & DVI output. I connect my motherboard to monitor using DVI to VGA connector. It's working.
Yesterday I installed windows 7 OS and also installed monitor drivers(downloaded from viewsonic site - signed version)
When i set display resolution to 1440 x 900. It's not setting it.it sets back to 800x600.
What should i do to make resolution to 1440x900 (monitor resolution)?
DVI to VGA causing this problem or i need to do any trick?
Any link to download drivers
Please guide me..

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: How are you setting the display resolution? Are you using the Win7 interface or the Intel utility?  Have you installed all the Intel drivers for that motherboard, especially the Intel HD Graphics driver? http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop+Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+6+Series+Chipset+Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Desktop+Board+DH67GD

Comment: I use windows7 interface to set resolution.I installed intel mobo drivers

Answer (score 0):

Hit CTRL+R and type dxdiag, go to video tab and check if you have your gpu identified correctly, if not theh
You have install not just intel mobo drivers, but intel gpu drivers aswell, that should solve your issue.

Else try to delete drivers that you have installed, and then install it over